# OpenSSL DecryptFinal wrong final block length

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

I'm using OpenSSL and C language to make an application for encryption and decryption. I have an header file (which I have to use as it is, without the possibility to modify) which is:

```
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define CSM_SYM_KEY_MAX_SIZE 1024

typedef uint32_t uint32;
typedef uint16_t uint16;
typedef uint8_t uint8;
typedef uint16 Csm_ConfigIdType;
typedef uint8 Csm_AlignType; 


typedef struct Csm_SymKeyType{
    uint32 length;
    Csm_AlignType data[CSM_SYM_KEY_MAX_SIZE];
} Csm_SymKeyType;

typedef enum Std_ReturnType {
    E_OK,               /*  Request successful  */                   
    E_NOT_OK,           /*  Request failed  */                                  
    CSM_E_BUSY,         /*  Request failed, service is still busy   */          
    CSM_E_SMALL_BUFFER  /*  The provider buffer is too small to store the result    */
} Std_ReturnType;

/* Encryption functions */
Std_ReturnType Csm_SymBlockEncryptStart(Csm_ConfigIdType cfgId,    Csm_SymKeyType *keyPtr);
Std_ReturnType Csm_SymBlockEncryptUpdate(Csm_ConfigIdType cfgId, const uint8 *plaintextPtr, uint32 plainTextLength, 
                                        uint8 *cipherTextPtr, uint32 *plainTextLengthPtr);
Std_ReturnType Csm_SymBlockEncryptFinish(Csm_ConfigIdType cfgId);

/* Decryption functions */
Std_ReturnType Csm_SymBlockDecryptStart(Csm_ConfigIdType cfgId, Csm_SymKeyType *keyPtr);
Std_ReturnType Csm_SymBlockDecryptUpdate(Csm_ConfigIdType cfgId, const uint8 *cipherTextPtr, uint32 cipherTextLength, 
                                        uint8 *plainTextPtr, uint32 *cipherTextLengthPtr);
Std_ReturnType Csm_SymBlockDecryptFinish(Csm_ConfigIdType cfgId);
```

The code which I wrote is:

```
#include "CSM_library.h"

EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;
uint32 ciphertext_len;
uint32 plaintext_len;
uint32 ct_len;
uint32 pt_len;
uint8 *ciphertext;
uint8 *plaintext;
uint8 *iv;

void OPENSSL_config();

Csm_SymKeyType *keyPtr;

void handleErrors(void){

    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
}

void ctx_init(){

    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    OPENSSL_config(NULL);
    ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    if (ctx == NULL)
        handleErrors();

    return;

}

void ctx_finish(){

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    EVP_cleanup();
    return;
}

Std_ReturnType Csm_SymBlockEncryptStart(Csm_ConfigIdType cfgId, Csm_SymKeyType *keyPtr){

    uint32 ret;
    ct_len = 0;
    ciphertext_len = 0;
    ctx_init();
    ret = EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, keyPtr->data, iv);
    if (ret != 1)
        handleErrors();
    return E_OK;
}

Std_ReturnType Csm_SymBlockEncryptUpdate(Csm_ConfigIdType cfgId, const uint8 *plainTextPtr, uint32 plainTextLength, 
                                        uint8 *cipherTextPtr, uint32 *plainTextLengthPtr){

    uint32 ret;
    ret = EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, cipherTextPtr, &ct_len, plainTextPtr, plainTextLength);
    if (ret != 1)
        handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len = ct_len;
    ciphertext = cipherTextPtr;
    return E_OK;
}

Std_ReturnType Csm_SymBlockEncryptFinish(Csm_ConfigIdType cfgId){

    uint32 ret;
    ret = EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + ct_len, &ct_len);
    if (ret != 1)
        handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len += ct_len;
    ctx_finish();
    return E_OK;
}

Std_ReturnType Csm_SymBlockDecryptStart(Csm_ConfigIdType cfgId, Csm_SymKeyType *keyPtr){

    uint32 ret;
    pt_len = 0;
    plaintext_len = 0;
    ctx_init();
    ret = EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, keyPtr->data, iv);
    if (ret != 1)
        handleErrors();
    return E_OK;
}

Std_ReturnType Csm_SymBlockDecryptUpdate(Csm_ConfigIdType cfgId, const uint8 *cipherTextPtr, uint32 cipherTextLength, 
                                        uint8 *plainTextPtr, uint32 *cipherTextLengthPtr){

    uint32 ret;
    ret = EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plainTextPtr, &pt_len, cipherTextPtr, cipherTextLength);
    if (ret != 1)
        handleErrors(); 
    plaintext_len = pt_len;
    plaintext = plainTextPtr;
    return E_OK;
}

Std_ReturnType Csm_SymBlockDecryptFinish(Csm_ConfigIdType cfgId){

    uint32 ret;
    ret = EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + pt_len, &pt_len);
    if (ret != 1)
        handleErrors(); 
    plaintext_len += pt_len;
    ctx_finish();
    return E_OK;
}

int main(){

    Csm_ConfigIdType cfgId;
    uint32 key_size;
    uint32 iv_size;
    uint32 cipherTextLength;
    uint32 plainTextLength;
    uint32 *plainTextLengthPtr;
    uint32 *cipherTextLengthPtr;
    const uint8 *plainTextPtr = "In the midway of this our mortal life, I found me in a gloomy wood";
    const uint8 *cipherTextPtr2;


    key_size = EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH;    //64
    iv_size = 4;

    plainTextLength = strlen(plainTextPtr);
    plainTextLengthPtr = &plainTextLength;

    uint8 cipherTextPtr[128];
    uint8 plainTextPtr2[128]; 

    uint8 key[key_size];
    iv = malloc(iv_size);


    /*  create key and inizialization vector  */
    RAND_bytes(key, key_size);
    RAND_bytes(iv, iv_size);

    keyPtr = malloc(sizeof(Csm_SymKeyType));
    if (keyPtr == NULL){
        printf("malloc() fails");
        exit(1);
    }

    keyPtr->length = key_size;
    memcpy(keyPtr->data, key, key_size);

    /*  encryption  */
    Csm_SymBlockEncryptStart(cfgId, keyPtr);
    Csm_SymBlockEncryptUpdate(cfgId, plainTextPtr, plainTextLength, cipherTextPtr, plainTextLengthPtr);
    Csm_SymBlockEncryptFinish(cfgId);

    printf("Ciphertext is:\n");
    BIO_dump_fp(stdout, (const char *)cipherTextPtr, cipherTextLength);

    /*  decryption  */
    Csm_SymBlockDecryptStart(cfgId, keyPtr);
    cipherTextPtr2 = cipherTextPtr;
    cipherTextLength = strlen(cipherTextPtr2);

    cipherTextLengthPtr = &cipherTextLength;
    Csm_SymBlockDecryptUpdate(cfgId, cipherTextPtr2, cipherTextLength, plainTextPtr2, cipherTextLengthPtr);
    Csm_SymBlockDecryptFinish(cfgId);

    plainTextPtr2[strlen(plainTextPtr2)] = '\0';
    printf("Plaintext: %s\nof length %i\n", plainTextPtr2, strlen(plainTextPtr2));

    free(keyPtr);
    return 0;
}
```

I know the code can be written better than it is, but it's just a trial and I would just to make it work at this step.
The encryption is fine, the decryption phase is variable, sometimes it proceeds without errors, but the decryption is not correct (it adds something at the end and some newlines):

```
Plaintext: This is my plaintext!










                                x-gnu/libcrypto.
of length 48
```

Sometimes it give me this error during execution:

```
140614667638424:error:0606506D:digital envelope  routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc.c:581:
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Reading the error message I think it's something related to the decrypted block length, but I checked again and again the functions `EVP_DecryptUpdate()` and `EVP_DecryptFinal()` and they seems fine to me. Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the data to be decrypted an exact multiple of the block size (16-bytes for AES)? Explain what "adds something at the end " means, add the data from the last block decrypted in hexadecimal. Was padding used when the data was encrypted and if so that kind?

Comment: The problem may be related to your usage of ciphertext_len (a global variable for storing how many characters have been put into the 'cipherTextPtr' array), and cipherTextLength ( a local varaible in main, which is never updated).  Or it could be the definition in the include file misleads you on how to write Csm_SymBlockEncryptUpdate... because it says these are its parameters: (Csm_ConfigIdType cfgId, const uint8 *plaintextPtr, uint32 plainTextLength, uint8 *cipherTextPtr, uint32 *plainTextLengthPtr);  The last parm COULD have been meant to be *cipherTextLen.

Comment: I think you should reduce it a bit more. Just make everything global. Finding some stuff global and other stuff local makes it hard to follow what's going on. And its not clear to me what's going on with `plaintext_len` and `pt_len`. Usually you only need one (plus a temporary). Ditto for `ciphertext_len` and `ct_len`. Also, have you looked at [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki? That's really about as hard as it gets. They even use `EVP_aes_256_cbc` as an example.

Comment: I find the problem in the fact that after the *Finish* operations (both for encryption and decryption) I don't return the final version of the ciphertext (and plaintext as well), so the *Final* operations in my code are useless (and it's terribly wrong). So I have to find a way to return that value back, in order to make precise computations during decryption. Thank you for all your comments and advices.

Comment: I've got the same error when I encrypt on Windows but decrypt on Linux. I don't know the reason. The issue I can link to: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4746

Comment: @zaph Is there an additional step for the case that the unencrypted data is an exact multiple of the block size? I'm seeing a failure in the Finalize function in this case but I can't work out why.

Comment: If the data is a multiple of the block size add one block of padding.